# How to interface two leds and two push button with 8051?

Tags: c, 8051

i'm using 8051 mcu to do some tests.
i'm trying to use two input for two push buttons and two outputs for two Leds.
SW1 = push button 1
SW2 = push button 2
LED1 = led1
LED2 = led2

for example 
-if i push S1 the Led1 will glow continuously.
-if i push S2 the Led2 will glow continuously.

These two command works independently.

So here what i tried:
only S1 and Led1 are working.
Please help, thank you.

```
#include <reg51.h>

sbit S1 = P2^0;
sbit S2 = P2^1;

sbit Led = P1^0;
sbit Led2 = P1^1;

void main()
 {
    S1 = 1;
    S2 = 1;

     while(1)  // For ever 
       {
         if(S1 == 0)  // if press Push button
          { 
            Led = 0;// ON LED ( active low )
            while(S1 == 0);// Wait here for release of push button
          }
      Led = 1;
       }

{
  if (S2 == 0)
    {
      Led2 = 0;
      while (S2 == 0);
       }
       Led2 = 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have un paired or extra curly brackets.

```
void main() {
    S1 = 1;
    S2 = 1;

    while(1) {  // For ever 
      if(S1 == 0) {  // if press Push button
         Led = 0;// ON LED ( active low )
         while(S1 == 0);// Wait here for release of push button
      }
      Led = 1;
      } // LOOPS BACK TO WHILE
    { // ***EXTRA***
    if (S2 == 0) {
      Led2 = 0;
      while (S2 == 0);
    }
    Led2 = 1;

   } // While?
} // Main?
```

Fixed:

```
void main() {
    S1 = 1;
    S2 = 1;

    while(1) {  // For ever 
      if(S1 == 0) {  // if press Push button
         Led = 0;// ON LED ( active low )
         while(S1 == 0);// Wait here for release of push button
      }

      Led = 1;

      if (S2 == 0) {
         Led2 = 0;
         while (S2 == 0);
      }

      Led2 = 1;

   } // While
} // Main
```

Comment: If this helps, dont forget to upvote and accept. @MimiCracra

Answer (score 0):

the while(1) statement only encloses the S1 press handler code. count the curly braces { } and move the S2 handler code inside the set of matching curly braces that belong to the while.

```
while(1) // forever
{
    // all code goes here
    if(....) 
    {
    }
    if(...)
    {
    }
} // end of while(1)
// anything after this point never runs
```